# Create StringBuilder from byte[]

Tags: java, memory

Is there a way to create a `StringBuilder` from a `byte[]`?

I want to improve memory usage using `StringBuilder` but what I have first is a `byte[]`, so I have to create a `String` from the `byte[]` and then create the `StringBuilder` from the `String` and I don't see this solution as optimal.

Thanks

Comment: I dare say it's not theoretically optimal, but is it actually a *problem*? Have you done appropriate tests to show what impact this is having?

Comment: What is the next thing you are doing with that StringBuilder?

Comment: If you want more control over the decoding process and what memory it uses, you can directly use a [`CharsetDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) and decode into a dedicated `CharBuffer` (instead of using a `StringBuilder`).

Comment: and note that CharBuffer implements CharSequence, so you can also use it directly in many places.

Comment: Bare in mind that your byte array can only be converted into a String if you specify an encoding. In Java that's usually assumed to be UTF-8 if you don't specify, so you have to make sure that's correct your your array.

Comment: Given a byte[] is mutable, can you not use just the byte[]?

Comment: @MartinDow The encoding is platform specific and could be anything. UTF-8 is a common choice.

Comment: @MartinDow: "In Java that's assumed to be UTF-8 if you don't specify" I wish that was true. Would make for much less platform-dependent code.

Comment: @PeterLawrey & Thilo Fair point. I meant "usually" and have edited.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Basically, your best option seems to be using [CharsetDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) directly.

Here's how:

```
byte[] srcBytes = getYourSrcBytes();

//Whatever charset your bytes are endoded in
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();

//ByteBuffer.wrap simply wraps the byte array, it does not allocate new memory for it
ByteBuffer srcBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(srcBytes);
//Now, we decode our srcBuffer into a new CharBuffer (yes, new memory allocated here, no can do)
CharBuffer resBuffer = decoder.decode(srcBuffer);

//CharBuffer implements CharSequence interface, which StringBuilder fully support in it's methods
StringBuilder yourStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(resBuffer);
```

**ADDED:**

After some tests it seems that the simple `new String(bytes)` is much faster and it seems there is no simple way to make it faster than that. Here is the test I ran:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.CharacterCodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class ConsoleMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
        for (int i=0;i<19;i++) {
            sb1.append(sb1);
        }
        System.out.println("Size of buffer: "+sb1.length());
        byte[] src = sb1.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
        StringBuilder res;

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        res = testStringConvert(src);
        System.out.println("Conversion using String time (msec): "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));
        if (!res.toString().equals(sb1.toString())) {
            System.err.println("Conversion error");
        }

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        res = testCBConvert(src);
        System.out.println("Conversion using CharBuffer time (msec): "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));
        if (!res.toString().equals(sb1.toString())) {
            System.err.println("Conversion error");
        }
    }

    private static StringBuilder testStringConvert(byte[] src) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String s = new String(src, "UTF-8");
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(s);
        return b;
    }

    private static StringBuilder testCBConvert(byte[] src) throws CharacterCodingException {
        Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
        ByteBuffer srcBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(src);
        CharBuffer resBuffer = decoder.decode(srcBuffer);
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(resBuffer);
        return b;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Size of buffer: 13631488
Conversion using String time (msec): 91
Conversion using CharBuffer time (msec): 252
```

And a modified (less memory-consuming) version on IDEONE: [Here](http://ideone.com/jIY7V).

Comment: That does not seem to save any memory compared to just using a String. To make this useful, he has to continue using the CharBuffer instead of a StringBuilder.

Comment: @Thilo, hm, going to go check the StringBuilder sources, but you could be right.

Comment: @Thilo, seems you are wrong. If used with a temporary String variable (OP solution in question body), CharBuffer is converted into String, which is then copied into internal char array in StringBuilder. In my solution, CharBuffer is copied directly into internal char array in StringBuilder, using CharSequence methods. Therefore, we don't need 1 temporary String object in memory.

Comment: I don't think so. String(byte[]) uses StringCoding#decode, which just wraps a char[] as output that is then directly used to back the String (i.e. that CharBuffer is directly used by the String, no extra copy).

Comment: @Thilo Seems you are right indeed. There's some magic going on with that String conversion, I've made a simple test, and it seems my solution is 2.5 times slower than the one with strings.

Answer (score 4):

If it is short statements you want, then there is no way around the String step in between. The String constructor mixes conversion and object construction for convenience in a very common case, but there is no such convenience constructor for a StringBuilder.

If it is performance you are interested in, then you might avoid the intermediate String object by using something like this:

```
new StringBuilder(Charset.forName(charsetName).decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(inBytes)))
```

If you want to be able to fine-tune performance, you can control the decode process yourself. For example, you might want to avoid using too much memory, by using averageCharsPerByte as an estimate of how much memory will be needed. Instead of resizing the buffer if that estimate was too short, you could use the resulting StringBuilder to accumulate all the parts.

```
CharsetDecoder cd = Charset.forName(charsetName).newDecoder();
cd.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);
cd.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);
int lengthEstimate = Math.ceil(cd.averageCharsPerByte()*inBytes.length) + 1;
ByteBuffer inBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(inBytes);
CharBuffer outBuf = CharBuffer.allocate(lengthEstimate);
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(lengthEstimate);
CoderResult cr;
while (true) {
    cr = cd.decode(inBuf, outBuf, true);
    out.append(outBuf);
    outBuf.clear();
    if (cr.isUnderflow()) break;
    if (!cr.isOverflow()) cr.throwException();
}
cr = cd.flush(outBuf);
if (!cr.isUnderflow()) cr.throwException();
out.append(outBuf);
```

I doubt that the above code will be worth the effort in most applications, though. If an application is that interested in performance, it probably shouldn't be dealing with StringBuilder either, but handle everything at the buffer level.

Comment: "The String constructor mixes conversion and object construction for convenience in a very common case": Not just convenience -- conversion and construction are actually linked, the String directly uses the internal array used by the converter, so there is a performance benefit, too. So I think it would be very hard to beat it performancewise (your approach seems to be at best equivalent, see also @Max's answer).

Comment: Talking about the (StringCoding)[http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/lang/StringCoding.java] implementation of OpenJDK: yes, it uses the same array, if all of the following conditions hold:

- The decoder was shipped with the JDK
- The size estimate was correct

For e.g. UTF-8, if there is a single multibyte sequence in the input, an array copy will be necessary here as well. Which will probably result in equal performance, no worse than my suggestions.